# Frequently update user data

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm using RxJava2, Retrofit, and OkHttp in my Android App.
I have a user's data, and I want to update the data frequently, because any response takes about 4 seconds minimum in my app (WordPress slow responses).

**And yes, I HAVE to use WordPress, that's not my choice, it's the client's**

The design of my app is scrollable tabs, and one of the tabs contains the user data. The data is being updated when the user starts the app.

I'm not sure if I can use time based requests, like every 4 minutes, because that would give big traffic on the data server.

I want to be able to update the user's data frequently, without any over done traffic on the server. Is there anyway I can observe values on the database and do something when the data changes?

Comment: firebase real-time database gives this feature. They used open connection but have very good filtering of data which is to send and which one is redundent.

Comment: If you use Room Database you can get updates when data in database changes using query that returns `Flowable`

Comment: @Tuby Not sure if you read the question fully. I'm using Wordpress as my backend, that can't be changed. I'm not looking for another set of database, I'm looking for a way to deal with my current database.